# Adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged doesn't work

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have adapter for my listView and i want to update my adapter using NotifyDataSetChanged(), but it doesn't work for me. That's how I add data in my adapter:

```
if (Messages.Count != 0) {
    ChatAdapter = new BubbleAdapter (this, Messages);
    if(listViewChat.Adapter == null) {
        listViewChat.Adapter = ChatAdapter;
    } else {
        ChatAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

But like I said it does not work...
If i update using this way, my listView is scrolling to top:

```
ChatAdapter = new BubbleAdapter (this, Messages);
listViewChat.Adapter = ChatAdapter;
```

Comment: Is Message an array of object?

Comment: It is List<messageBubble>. Message bubble it's my class where I have message and some data about message

Comment: Please look at the modified code I mentioned below. I also faced a same issue before and resolved with that idea.

Comment: Try wrap the NotifyDataSetChanged in the RunUiThread RunOnUiThread(() => Adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged());

Answer (score 0):

Please look at below code. You have to do similar to what I mentioned below. As I don't have your whole code snippet, so I modified the codes you mentioned:

```
ArrayList<MessageBubble> MessagesAll = new ArrayList<MessageBubble>();
ChatAdapter = new BubbleAdapter (this, MessagesAll);
listViewChat.setAdapter(ChatAdapter);

MessageBubble Messages = new MessageBubble();
Messages.setMessage("Hi");
if (Messages.Count != 0) {
    MessagesAll.add(Messages);
    ChatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Plase let me know if you still not succeeded.

Comment: @Adept22 I'm sure you are doing mistake some where. If you can post me the whole code along with your adapter then only I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
listViewChat.setAdapter(ChatAdapter);
```

You can replace the entire block with that. If the list is empty the adapter will be empty as well, and the listview will be refreshed with zero items.

Answer (score 0):

Use ChatAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated(); instead of  ChatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Might not be a good idea. Semantically, `.notifyDataSetInvalidated` is supposed to mean that the data is no longer visible while `.notifyDataSetChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, I would like to thank each and everyone of the contributors of stack. I'm sure I owe you more gratitude than I can give.

This question has taken way too much of my time. For the folks that are still looking for a solution:

1. the performFilter should remain as is.
2. the publishResults should be as simple as:

   mIngredientList = (ArrayList) results.values;
   adapter.clear();
   if (mIngredientList != null) {
       for (int i = 0; i < mIngredientList.size(); i++)
         adapter.add(mIngredientList.get(i));
   }
3. the trick is this:
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

   mIngredientAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence.toString());
      mItemList.setAdapter(mIngredientAdapter);
   }
   Not re-adding the adapter, doesn't seem to work.